# Problemas en relaciones de tablas de Foreign Key en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Hola tengo problemas en las relaciones de las tablas con Foreign Key, ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

CREATE TABLE `activosfijos` (
`ActivoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Descripcion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`DepartamentoID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Ubicacion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Valor` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`FechaAdquisicion` date NOT NULL,
`ProveedorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `almacenes` (
`AlmacenID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Nombre_almacen` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Ubicacion` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`ProductoID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Producto_nombre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Unidades` int(11) NOT NULL,
`OrdenID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ID_Checklist_tool` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `aplicacion` (
`AplicacionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Uso_material` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Ubicacion_aplicacion` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `checklist_tool` (
`ID_checklist_tool` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Estado` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Encargado` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Autorizado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`Admin_autorizador` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Encargado_fecha` date NOT NULL,
`AlmacenID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ProductoID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `cotizaciones` (
`CotizacionesID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ProductoID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Producto_nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`ProveedorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Nombre_proveedor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Unidades` int(11) NOT NULL,
`CostoU` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`Fecha` date NOT NULL,
`Subtotal` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`Impuesto` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `departamento` (
`DepartamentoID` int(6) NOT NULL,
`Departamento` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Ubicacion` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `ord_compras` (
`OrdenID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ProveedorID` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`Nombre_proveedor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`ProductoID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Producto_nombre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Unidades` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Costo` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`SolicitudID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`UsuarioID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Usuario_autorizado` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Fecha_aut` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Autorizado` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`Departamento` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

INSERT INTO `ord_compras` (`OrdenID`, `ProveedorID`, `Nombre_proveedor`, `ProductoID`, `Producto_nombre`, `Unidades`, `Costo`, `SolicitudID`, `UsuarioID`, `Usuario_autorizado`, `Fecha_aut`, `Autorizado`, `Departamento`) VALUES
(1, 123, 'Proveedor A', 123, 'Producto A', 2, 2500.00, 1, 1, 'Damaris Varela', '2023-12-01', 1, 'Almacen'),
(657395, 1, '', 101, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1'),
(657396, 2, '', 1, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Dirección');

CREATE TABLE `presupuesto` (
`PresupuestoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Mes` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Año` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Saldo` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`OrdenID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`UsuarioID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `productos` (
`ProductoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Nombre_almacen` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`AlmacenID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Producto_nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Unidad` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Unidades` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Costo` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`AplicacionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Uso_material` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Ubicacion_aplicacion` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `proveedores` (
`ProveedorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Nombre_proveedor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`CSF` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Cuenta_bancaria` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Cuenta_interbancaria` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Banco_receptor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Razon_social` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Contador_responsable` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Distribucion_comercial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Tipo_regimen` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Telefono_proveedor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Direccion_proveedor` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `proyecto` (
`ProyectoID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`PresupuestoID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`AlmacenID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ProductoID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Unidades` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`CotizacionesID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ProveedorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Fecha` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Clave_presupuestaria` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Nombre_presupuestario` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `rol` (
`Rol_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Nombre_Rol` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`DepartamentoID` int(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `solicitudes` (
`SolicitudID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Fecha_solicitud` date NOT NULL,
`Cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Autorizado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`UsuarioID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Rol_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ID_Checklist_tool` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
`UsuarioID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Ap_paterno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Ap_materno` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`CorreoElectronico` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`Contraseña` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`DepartamentoID` int(6) NOT NULL,
`Rol_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Nombre_rol` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;

ALTER TABLE `activosfijos`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ActivoID`),
ADD KEY `FK_ActivosProveedor_ProveedorID` (`ProveedorID`),
ADD KEY `FK_ActivosDepartamento_DepartamentoID` (`DepartamentoID`);

ALTER TABLE `almacenes`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`AlmacenID`),
ADD KEY `FK_AlmacenesProducto_ProductoID` (`ProductoID`),
ADD KEY `FK_AlmacenesOrden_OrdenID` (`OrdenID`),
ADD KEY `FK_AlmacenesCT_CTID` (`ID_Checklist_tool`);

ALTER TABLE `aplicacion`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`AplicacionID`);

ALTER TABLE `checklist_tool`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_checklist_tool`),
ADD KEY `FK_CTAlmacenes_Almacenes` (`AlmacenID`),
ADD KEY `FK_CTProducto_ProductoID` (`ProductoID`);

ALTER TABLE `cotizaciones`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`CotizacionesID`),
ADD KEY `FK_CotizacionesProducto_ProductoID` (`ProductoID`),
ADD KEY `FK_CotizacionesProveedor_Proveedor ID` (`ProveedorID`);

ALTER TABLE `departamento`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`DepartamentoID`);

ALTER TABLE `ord_compras`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`OrdenID`),
ADD KEY `FK_OCSolicitud_SolicitudesID` (`SolicitudID`),
ADD KEY `FK_OCUsuarios_UsuarioID` (`UsuarioID`);

ALTER TABLE `presupuesto`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`PresupuestoID`),
ADD KEY `FK_PresupuestoOrden_OrdenID` (`OrdenID`),
ADD KEY `FK_PresupuestoUsuario_UsuarioID` (`UsuarioID`);

ALTER TABLE `productos`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ProductoID`),
ADD KEY `FK_ProductosAlmacen_AlmacenID` (`AlmacenID`),
ADD KEY `FK_ProductosAplicacion_AplicacionID` (`AplicacionID`);

ALTER TABLE `proveedores`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ProveedorID`);

ALTER TABLE `proyecto`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ProyectoID`),
ADD KEY `PresupuestoID` (`PresupuestoID`),
ADD KEY `FK_ProyectoProducto_ProductoID` (`ProductoID`),
ADD KEY `FK_ProyectoCotizaciones_CotizacionesID` (`CotizacionesID`),
ADD KEY `FK_ProyectoProveedor_ProveedorID` (`ProveedorID`);

ALTER TABLE `rol`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Rol_ID`),
ADD KEY `FK_RolDepartamento_DepartamentoID` (`DepartamentoID`);

ALTER TABLE `solicitudes`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SolicitudID`),
ADD KEY `FK_SolicitudesUsuarios_UsuarioID` (`UsuarioID`),
ADD KEY `FK_SolicitudesRol_` (`Rol_ID`),
ADD KEY `FK_SolicitudesCT_CTID` (`ID_Checklist_tool`);

ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`UsuarioID`),
ADD KEY `FK_UsuariosRol_RolID` (`Rol_ID`),
ADD KEY `FK_UsuariosDepartamento_DepartamentoID` (`DepartamentoID`);

ALTER TABLE `activosfijos`
MODIFY `ActivoID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=123457;

ALTER TABLE `almacenes`
MODIFY `AlmacenID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=124;

ALTER TABLE `aplicacion`
MODIFY `AplicacionID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `checklist_tool`
MODIFY `ID_checklist_tool` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `cotizaciones`
MODIFY `CotizacionesID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `departamento`
MODIFY `DepartamentoID` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `ord_compras`
MODIFY `OrdenID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=657397;

ALTER TABLE `presupuesto`
MODIFY `PresupuestoID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `productos`
MODIFY `ProductoID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=102;

ALTER TABLE `proyecto`
MODIFY `ProyectoID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `rol`
MODIFY `Rol_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `solicitudes`
MODIFY `SolicitudID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
MODIFY `UsuarioID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=215944;

ALTER TABLE `presupuesto`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PresupuestoOrden_OrdenID` FOREIGN KEY (`OrdenID`) REFERENCES `ord_compras` (`OrdenID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_PresupuestoUsuario_UsuarioID` FOREIGN KEY (`UsuarioID`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`UsuarioID`);

ALTER TABLE `solicitudes`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_SolicitudesCT_CTID` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Checklist_tool`) REFERENCES `checklist_tool` (`ID_checklist_tool`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_SolicitudesRol_` FOREIGN KEY (`Rol_ID`) REFERENCES `rol` (`Rol_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_SolicitudesUsuarios_UsuarioID` FOREIGN KEY (`UsuarioID`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`UsuarioID`);
COMMIT;